# Moving Circle in customer painter with gesture detector not working

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, gesturedetector, flutter-custompainter

I am trying to use  gesture detector to move the red point that i draw in custom painter around the xy plot that i draw in a seperate custom painter but i cant seem to get it to work. I would like to thank any help give in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
 }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isDown = false;
  var xPos = 5.0;
  var yPos = 5.0;

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                ),
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (_, constraints) => Container(
                          width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                          height: constraints.widthConstraints().maxHeight,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Stack(children: [
                            // plotting X Y axis
                            SizedBox(
                                width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                                height:
                                    constraints.widthConstraints().maxHeight,
                                child: CustomPaint(painter: PlotPainter())),

                            GestureDetector(
                              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                                final tapPos = details.localPosition;

                                if (tapPos.dx > 5 &&
                                    tapPos.dx <
                                        constraints
                                            .widthConstraints()
                                            .maxWidth) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    xPos = tapPos.dx - 5;
                                    yPos = tapPos.dy - 5;
                                  });
                                }

                                if (tapPos.dy > 5 &&
                                    tapPos.dy <
                                        constraints
                                            .widthConstraints()
                                            .maxHeight) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    yPos = tapPos.dy - 5;
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                                  height:
                                      constraints.widthConstraints().maxHeight,
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: PointsPainter(xPos, yPos))),
                            ),
                            // plotting points
                          ]),
                        )),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }));
  }
}

class PointsPainter extends CustomPainter {
  PointsPainter(this.xPos, this.yPos);
  double xPos;
  double yPos;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement points
    final midY = size.height / 2;
    final midX = size.width / 2;
    final Circlepaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = Colors.red;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(xPos, yPos), 5, Circlepaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }
}

// drawing the x y axis
class PlotPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final midY = size.height / 2;
    final midX = size.width / 2;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
    final textPainterx = TextPainter(
        text: const TextSpan(
          text: 'x',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    final textPaintery = TextPainter(
        text: const TextSpan(
          text: 'y',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 13,
          ),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    // X axis
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, midY), Offset(size.width, midY), paint);
    //y Axis
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(midX, 0), Offset(midX, size.height), paint);
    //arrow head of the X-Y Axis
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width, midY), Offset(size.width - 5, midY - 3), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width, midY), Offset(size.width - 5, midY + 3), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(midX, 0), Offset(midX - 3, 5), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(midX, 0), Offset(midX + 3, 5), paint);

    textPainterx.layout();
    textPaintery.layout();
    // Draw the text  X at the X axis
    textPainterx.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width - 7, midY + 1));
    // Draw the text  y at the Y axis
    textPaintery.paint(canvas, Offset(midX + 5, 0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

**The Problem was that you did not wrap the custom painter inside gesture detector now that is working fine**
now you only have to add condition that it will not go more up and down on given height